# QPSQL драйвер для Qt

Tags: qt, postgresql

Не получается собрать драйвер postgresql для Qt.Cледовал инструкции с официального сайта
Вот что выдает после команды make[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: OS:Xubuntu 18.04
Qt version: 5.11.0
Postgresql 10.5

Comment: какой именно инструкции следуешь и в чём цель самостоятельной сборки?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь собрать плагин версии 5.11 библиотекой Qt версии, если не ошибаюсь, 5.9.
Сами посмотрите: /usr/...  Это путь к библиотеке линукса. 
Чтобы справиться, наверняка,  Вы и сами сможете добавить путь к нужным библиотекам в LD_LIBRARY_PATH. И использовать qmake от 5.11 версии.
В 5.9 у qsqlfield, вроде, еще нет метода setTableName.